# can you exponentially stretch out keyframes?

Tags: animation, keyframes

I am trying to have an animated rig ramp smoothly into slow motion.
In after effect I would pre-compose and then ramp using time displacement.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/xWbGS.jpg

Is there any way of doing the same 'ramp' in blender?
https://i.stack.imgur.com/FRML2.jpg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should try "Action constraint": create a new controller bone, add an action constraint to a bone (let we call it "First") and set it as controlled by your action via one of the new bone trasform channels (maybe X Loc).

Then select all bones involved in driving the animation, select the "First" bone last (so it's active) and press Ctrl C > copy selected constraints, select the action constraint and confirm.

Unhook the action from the rig (but give it the shield icon, so that it doesn't get deleted during quit).

Now moving the controller bone on X axis will trigger the whole action, and you will have a single graph editor curve that will control the speed of the action.

Comment: I nearly did it I think but it still isn't working. Please can you have a look here at where I am going wrong? we.tl/t-rswwBpveXb

Comment: [<img src="https://blend-exchange.com/embedImage.png?bid=Rj2lepKx" />](https://blend-exchange.com/b/Rj2lepKx/) First bone and control bone are different: as first I used hips (but it could be any bone, a finger, an arm, the head, it doesn't matter, it's just to write the constraint, then copy it to all others involved bones).

Comment: Thank you, Josh.

Answer (score 1):

Change from timeline to graph editor, select the "vertex", press R to rotate as you like.

[image]

Comment: Yes but but there are lots of different parts: https://imgur.com/a/QZiFFwy

Comment: Yes, but that wasn’t part of your question. You should specify your question to your needs - and you shouldn’t critique answers after they have made and then edit your question: this might lead to that people don’t want to help you anymore in the future. But …that’s your decision.